# Scatter plot legend with respect to colour [Python3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I have this MWE of six points to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(1,2,marker= 'o', color='darkred')
plt.scatter(3,5,marker= 'o', color='yellowgreen')
plt.scatter(11,21,marker= 'o', color='black')
plt.scatter(4,6,marker= 'o', color='blue')
plt.scatter(8,11,marker= 'o', color='yellowgreen')
plt.scatter(2,3,marker= 'o', color='darkred')
plt.show()
```

I would like to write a **legend based on colour** e.g

blue --> first_experiment

yelowgreen --> second_experiment

and so on.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `label` option:

```
plt.scatter(1,2,marker= 'o', color='darkred',label='first')
plt.scatter(3,5,marker= 'o', color='yellowgreen', label='second')
plt.scatter(11,21,marker= 'o', color='black')
plt.scatter(4,6,marker= 'o', color='blue')
plt.scatter(8,11,marker= 'o', color='yellowgreen')
plt.scatter(2,3,marker= 'o', color='darkred')

# add the legend
plt.legend()

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: No you were right, in addition the answer should be associated to the question itself not to the intent of the author or to the fact that the mwe doesn't explain the problem behind. Sorry.